# Jquery: confirm before click action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a checkbox in my form. I want to ask the user for confirmation before he checks the box. However, the "confirm" message automatically comes up AFTER the box gets ticked. I want to make it so the user can "cancel", and it's as if he never checked the box to begin with.

Here's my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.checkme').click(function(){
    text_area_id = "#" + $(this).val();
    if ($(text_area_id).attr('hidden')) {
      $(text_area_id).attr('hidden', false);
    } else{
      if ($(text_area_id).val() != '') {
        if (confirm("Clear text for \'" + $(this).val().replace(/_/g, " ") + "\'?")) {
          $(text_area_id).attr('hidden', true);
          $(text_area_id).val('');
          $(this).attr('checked', true);
          $('.checkme').attr('checked', true);
        }
      } else {
        $(text_area_id).attr('hidden', true);
        $('.checkme').attr('checked', true);
      }
    }
  });
```

Note the "confirm" box. I want that to come up upon clicking the checkmark box -- but BEFORE the box actually gets ticked.

So I'm guess I'm looking for a jquery function like

```
.before_click(function(){ ...
```

instead of

```
.click(function(){ ...
```

Or something like that...?

Answer (score 2):

Just set the checked attribute of checkbox based on your `confirm` `boolean` value. `window.confirm` returns `true` or `false`

```js
$(".checkme").on('click',function(e){
  var r = confirm("Are you sure?!");
  $(this).attr('checked',r);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkme"/>Check me
```